# Changing arrow on drop down menu?

Tags: html, css

You can view an example of the page I'm having a problem with here:

http://demo.easythemepro.com/?themedemo=AnimeLight

On the right side of the bottom bar, you'll see an option to select different themes.  I'm trying to change the down arrow to an image.  Here's my code:

```
background: url("http://www.easythemepro.com/img/arrow-right.png") no-repeat scroll 95% 53% #2B2B2B;
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?  My image doesn't appear to be showing on my end...

Comment: You need to create a pseudo-dropdown arrow - Absolute position a div in the wrapper with this bg - and somehow hide the background of the select.

Comment: I'm not really trying to style the arrow itself, I'm more trying to remove it so that my image shows instead...

Comment: Absolute position a div in the wrapper with this bg - and somehow hide the background of the select

Comment: I can see the arrow. What exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `default.css` file, I see the following (edited):

```
.wptdb_jumpbar_select option {
  background: url("http://www.easythemepro.com/img/arrow-right.png") no-repeat scroll 95% 53% #2B2B2B;
}
```

... but inspecting the page, it looks like the styles you want to change are for `.wptdb_jumpbar_select`.

So you're applying your CSS to the wrong element. Try:

```
.wptdb_jumpbar_select {
  background: url("http://www.easythemepro.com/img/arrow-right.png") no-repeat scroll 95% 53% #2B2B2B;
}
```